# NSTableView alternative row colors with NSArrayController

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

So I'm using NSArrayController with my NSTableView and I want to show custom row color even NSArrayController doesn't have any objects.

Normally without Cocoa bindings I can just "cheat" my numberOfRows like this:

```
var dataStore = [Person]()

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    if dataStore.count < 20 {
        return 20
    } else {
        return dataStore.count
    }
}
```

And then getting custom row colors...

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, didAddRowView rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
    if row % 2 == 0 { rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor() }
    else { rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor.reColor() }
}
```

How I can get same effect for empty table view with Cocoa bindings?

Comment: The latter method is a delegate method, and you can still use those regardless of bindings, which really replace the datasource methods

Comment: Yes I know, but I need to get that working even there isn't  any data. And that didAddRowView only works after added some data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about code for mac app but in ios app, I can easily achieve your need with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet. I will try it soon.

Comment: I dont know much about iOS, but I thin that's not the case with OS X. When I selectalternating rows for table view, they are all in different colours and if I understanded right colors are from `NSColor.controlAlternatingRowBackgroundColors()`.

It would be nice if somehow I could change them.